# How can I create a new dataframe that contains the difference values from comparing two other dataframes?

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, statistics

Let's say I have two dataframes/datasets, `df1` and `df2`, that have matching rows/row names and columns/column names. From these two datasets I want to create a third, `df3`, that contains the difference of `df1` minus `df2`.

[click for crude example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaELY.png)

Additionally, it would be over-the-top amazing if these differences in df3 could be formatted like a ticker, with positive differences in green font/green up arrow and negative differences in red font/red down arrow, but that would be extra.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should do some research before posting a question.

```
df1.subtract(df2)
```